# User validation in SSRS

Tags: validation, reporting-services, mdx

Is it possible to limit the user to write a number between 1 and 100 for a parameter within an SSRS?

Is it possible to write a function or write an MDX expression such as:

```
=IIf(Parameters!userPercent.Value <= 100 And Parameters!userPercent.Value >= 1, true, false)
```

and obtain a user-friendly error message?

I tried inserting the above expression in the default value tab for the parameter, but when previewing the report, the field turned out to be disabled

Comment: Are you looking for any number or only integers? My first thought is to write a quick query to generate numbers 1 to 100 and use it as a data source. Then make your parameter a drop down and have the user choose (you can type the number to have it select the correct one) from the values.  But if it could be any decimal number between 1 and 100, that might be more difficult.

Comment: I thought of a quick query to generate numbers from 1 to 100, but now I'm thinking that if it is possible, I generate javascript validation code on the parameters themselves, if this is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a custom code.